# Why doesn't access rules apply to a non-root group?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the [interrupt()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.interrupt%28%29) method of the class [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), we have the [checkAccess](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.checkAccess%28%29) called which in turn calls [SecurityManager#checkAccess(Thread)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/SecurityManager.java#SecurityManager.checkAccess%28java.lang.Thread%29). Now, consider the sources of the `SecurityManager.checkAccess(Thread)` method:

```
public void checkAccess(Thread t) {
     if (t == null) {
         throw new NullPointerException("thread can't be null");
     }
     if (t.getThreadGroup() == rootGroup) { //1
         checkPermission(SecurityConstants.MODIFY_THREAD_PERMISSION);
     } else {
         // just return
     }
 }
```

At `//1` we make a comparison if the thread belongs to the root group and if not, we don't apply access rules provided by the `SecurityManager` instance. So, I wrote the following sample:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Thread t = new Thread();
    System.out.println(t.getThreadGroup()); //prints java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    System.out.println(t.getThreadGroup().getParent());  //prints java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/k6aN9G)

and found out that threads created with `Thread`'s constructors don't belong to the `rootGroup`. So, the permissions specified in the `java.policy` file (in particularly) will never be applied ti threads we create ourselves.

Is there some reason for that? I mean, to apply permissions to the only root group?

Comment: What would be the rationale of blocking thread interactions ("modify") between threads of an application? A threaded Java app isn't a "core wars" arena, where programmers vie for the most robust thread. -- What is at the bottom of this and one other similar question?

Comment: @laune Don't know, obviously. But I use the `interrupt()` in my application which throws `SecurityException`. So I need to know how and under what circumstances it does so....

Comment: Interesting. Which thread are you hitting?

Comment: @laune I'm implementing the Future interface and I need to interrupt the thread performing a computation when the [cancel(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) method is called with the corresponding argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the thinking is that it is generally safe (not a security issue) for a thread to be allowed to interrupt, etcetera threads that are not system threads.

Note that the javadoc says this:

> *"If the thread argument is a system thread (belongs to the thread group with a null parent) then this method calls checkPermission with the RuntimePermission("modifyThread") permission. If the thread argument is not a system thread, this method just returns silently."*
>
> *"Applications that want a stricter policy should override this method. ....."*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it explains everything. But what JavaDocs did you quote?

Comment: The javadoc for the `SecurityManager.checkAccess(Thread t)` method.  (Did you even look?)

Comment: No, didn't think that it was from there. I looked for them in the Thread's docs